# Dynamically created command is disabled on Eclipse Juno (Eclipse RCP development)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

I have a class that creates some menu contributions dynamically:

```
public class DynamicHelpMenuFactory extends ExtensionContributionFactory {
...
 public void createContributionItems(IServiceLocator sl, IContributionRoot ad) {
...
  ICommandService commandService = getCommandService();
...
  // create the command
  Command command = commandService.getCommand("com.foo.bar");
  command.setHandler(new MyHandler());
  command.define("com.foo.bar.name", "com.foo.bar.description", "category.foo.bar");
...    
  // create the menu contribution
...
 }
...
}
```

This does not work on Eclipse **Juno**. The call `command.define(...)` replaces the specified handler with `MakeHandlersGo` handler and the menu contributions remain disabled (but they are shown).

I tried to call the `command.setHandler(...)` after the `command.define(...)` which made the menu contributions enabled, but clicking on them throws:

`org.eclipse.core.commands.NotHandledException: There is no handler to execute for command com.foo.bar`

The code above works (the menu contribution is shown & clicking on it makes the handler to execute its action) **OK for any other Eclipse version tried** (Indigo, Kepler, Luna, Mars).

This seems to me as a bug in Eclipse IDE, but I was not able to find any relevant problems reported for Juno. Does Eclipse Juno need some specific way to create menu contributions dynamically?

Comment: Is the 3.8 or 4.2 version of Juno?

Comment: It is Juno 4.2.0

Comment: Juno 4.2 was a very early version of the Eclipse 4 series and had many problems.